# where do I get the "username" value from in spring security to pass to the loadUserByUsername(String username) method of UserDetailsService interface

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-data-jpa, basic-authentication

I am trying to get a user from the database by authenticating the user based on username and password. I am using basic authentication to do this.
I am sending username and password in the authorization header of the rest api

In my controller the getUser() method calls the getuser() method of the UserService class

```
 @GetMapping("/user/self")
public ResponseEntity<UserDto> getUser() {
    UserDto UserDto = userService.getUser();
    return new ResponseEntity<>(UserDto, HttpStatus.OK);
}

@PutMapping("/user/self")
public ResponseEntity<User> updateUser(@Valid @RequestBody Map<String, String> userMap, Principal principal) {
    String username = principal.getName();
    String firstname = userMap.get("firstName");
    String lastName = userMap.get("lastName");
    String password = BCrypt.hashpw(userMap.get("password"), BCrypt.gensalt(10));
    User user = userService.getUserByUserName(username);
    user.setFirstName(firstname);
    user.setLastName(lastName);
    user.setPassword(password);
    userService.save(user);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(user, HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
}
```

UserService class implements UserDetailsService and overrides the loadUserByUsername method that requires a username to be passed as an argument. my question is: how do I pass username to loadUserByUsername() method from my UserService class that I am calling from my controller. where does username value reside?
my understanding is - the Authentication Object contains user credentials that are passed to authentication object when a user types their credentials and send their request, how do I retrieve this username value

```
 @Service
     public class UserService implements UserDetailsService {

@Autowired
UserRepository userRepository;

public UserDto save(User user) {
    String hashedPassword = BCrypt.hashpw(user.getPassword(), BCrypt.gensalt(10));
    user.setPassword(hashedPassword);
    userRepository.save(user);
    UserDto userDto = new UserDto();
    userDto.setId(user.getId());
    userDto.setFirstName(user.getFirstName());
    userDto.setLastName(user.getLastName());
    userDto.setUserName(user.getUserName());
    userDto.setAccountUpdatedAt(user.getAccountUpdatedAt());
    userDto.setAccountCreatedAt(user.getAccountCreatedAt());
    return userDto;
}

@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String userName) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    User user = userRepository.findByUserName(userName);
    if (user == null) {
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException(userName + "was not found");
    }
    return new UserPrincipal(user);
}
```

here is my repository code:

```
 @Repository
    public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {

User findByUserName(String userName);
   }
```

here is my authentication code:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
DataSource dataSource;
@Autowired
private AuthenticationEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint;
@Autowired
UserService userService;


@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}

public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());

}


@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.cors().and().csrf().disable();
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/v1/user").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/v1/user/self").authenticated().and().httpBasic()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint);
 }
}
```

Comment: if using basic authentication, after a user has been logged in, the client will get a session cookie. In every request this session cookie will get returned to the server in each request. Using the id in the session cookie the server will populate the `Principal` with the user information. If you want to retrieve that information there are several ways you can read about them here https://www.baeldung.com/get-user-in-spring-security

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you dealing with JPA then in your case you have to use `userDetailsService` instead of `jdbcauthentication`, therefor your security class would look like this :

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private  UserService userService;
    
    public SecurityConfig(UserService userService){
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(10); // Number of rounds 
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(this.userService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }
}
```

then you can customize the authentication in the `UserService` class to satisfy the business need as the below sample :

```
@Service
public class UserService implements UserDetailsService {

    private final UserRepository userRepository;
    
    public UserService(UserRepository userRepository){
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

        Optional<User> user = userRepository.findByUsername(username);

        if(user.isPresent()){
            log.info("cretaed under User service : " + user.get());
            return user.get();
        }

        throw new UsernameNotFoundException("empty or invalud user");
    }
}
```

in addition, do not forget to create the `findByUsername` method in your repository also do not forget to implement `org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails` in your module class:

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

    Optional<User> findByUsername(String name);
}
```

Comment: thank you for taking the time to answer my question.  I need to clarify one thing.

``

Comment: @shahi you have to pass a user and password with every request in the header as `httpBasic` authentication and specify the role your in the config class for each endpoint

Comment: you can remove the entire `configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)` and instead just declare the user service as a `@Bean` and both the `UserDetailService` and the `PasswordEncoder` will be automatically insert by spring

Comment: @Toerktumlare yah I know that but for demonstration purposes, I have decided to make things simpler for him, if you have alternatives feel free to edit it

Comment: @MahmoudOdeh thank you!. doing this 
 `   @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(this.userService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    } `  
helped. instead of using jdbcauthentication().  

@Toerktumlare thank you! I was able to retrieve the current authenticated user from the Principal object 
  @GetMapping("/user/self")
    public ResponseEntity<UserDto> getUser(Principal principal) {
        String username = principal.getName();
        UserDto UserDto = userService.getUser(username);